# What hidden charactere could be on my code in JAVA?

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I am doing a lex analyzer and am facing some problems. After reading all the characters from the source code, I put them in a string and I'm reading character by character and doing the proper operations. In the end, this generates a list containing language tokens, spaces, breaklines and ... a damn character I can not identify and need to clean.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokenList.size(); i++) {
    // Remove Espacos
    if (tokenList.get(i).getLexema().equals(" ")) {
        tokenList.remove(i);
    }
    // Remove Strings Vazias
    else if (tokenList.get(i).getLexema().length() == 0) {
        print("ada");
        tokenList.remove(i);
    }
    // Remove Tabulação
    else if (tokenList.get(i).getLexema().equals("\t")) {
        tokenList.remove(i);
    }
    // Remove Quebras de Linha
    else if (tokenList.get(i).getLexema().equals("\n")) {
        print("ASD");
        tokenList.remove(i);
    }
}
```

From the following entry:

```
int a;
char n;
```

After all the analysis, and cleaning up, I get the following result:

```
00 - Lex: int
01 - Lex: a
02 - Lex: ;
03 - Lex: 
04 - Lex: char
05 - Lex: n
06 - Lex: ;
```

There is an empty space and I do not know how to remove it.

Comment: Are you talking about line 03? I suggest you print out the ascii value to see what character it is.

Comment: If you're running on Windows, could be `\r`

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should do something like `String lexema = tokenList.get(i).getLexema();` and then you can do `switch (lexema)` instead of the if...else chain.

Comment: Also, if you need further help, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Great idea @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Deleting tokens from the list as you iterate over the list? Almost certain to have bugs (not the one you are looking for, but more for you to find later ;-)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, the value that appears is 13, the char that represents Carriage Return.  I'll try to remove it.

Comment: @John3136, I don't have idea about how to do different. I search for a value. If it matches, I remove it. Could you tell me a better way to do that? Consider that this action happens only one time in the entire code.

Comment: @ValneyFaria Do some research - there are plenty of notes. Just think though you start with items [0..9]. i=0. You delete item [1]. What was [1] is now [0]. i++. so you never look at the item that started in [1]. In your case it may not be an issue. If you have a space followed by a \n you wont remove the \n.

Comment: MAAAAAANNN, What the **** I'm doing? Now I understand what's wrong here. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ValneyFaria Make sure you put your solution in the "Answers" section and accept it to make your Q&A more structured for future visitors.

Comment: Guys, WE DID IT! Thanks all of you for your help. I posted the solution on the question because I am new here and still don't know what to do when my problem is solved. If you could help me, it will be great. Thanks!

Comment: Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Well, those guys are incredible and I could solve my problem. The solution, using some better strategies of coding:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokenList.size(); i++) {
    String lexema = tokenList.get(i).getLexema();

    switch (lexema) {
        case "":
            tokenList.remove(i);
            i = i - 1;
            break;
        // Remove Espacos
        case " ":
            tokenList.remove(i);
            i = i - 1;
            break;
        // Remove Tabulações
        case "\t":
            tokenList.remove(i);
            i = i - 1;
            break;
        // Remove Quebras de Linha
        case "\n":
            tokenList.remove(i);
            i = i - 1; // DEIXAR SEM O BREAK
            break;
        // Remove Caractere Estranho
        case "\r":
            tokenList.remove(i);
            i = i - 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative and easier solution is to use `Character.isWhitespace()`. So your code could be as simple as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokenList.size(); i++) {
    String lexema = tokenList.get(i).getLexema();
    char c = lexema.charAt(0);

    if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
        tokenList.remove(i);
        i = i - 1;
    }
}
```